# When I use env files I got undefined when I read the vars

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I created a Vue application using `vue/cli`: `vue create my-vue`. I want to build this project in `next` mode (like `qa`, `stage`, `next` ...), so I followed the [steps in the Vue docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables). I created the `.env.next` file in the root project with this content:

```
FOO=next
```

In my `main.js`, I log it to the console:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

console.log({ f: process.env.FOO }); // <----- undefined. why?
console.log({ f: process.env.VUE_APP_FOO }); // <----- undefined. why?

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

After that, I run the build:

```
npm run build -- --mode next
```

**When I run the dist folder** in the console, I get `undefined`. I searched for "next" in the bundle, but it's not there.

Why? How can I use `.env` vars in my build output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the docs you've linked:

> Note that only `NODE_ENV`, `BASE_URL`, and **variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the *client bundle*** with `webpack.DefinePlugin`. It is to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.

For `FOO` to be available in the build output, rename it to `VUE_APP_FOO` in your `.env` file, and update references accordingly:

```js
console.log({ f: process.env.VUE_APP_FOO })
```